# How can I make a date field appear when a checkbox is unchecked in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, datepicker

HTML Helper

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cb_FinalApproval, "Final Approval Date", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
    <div class="col-md-offset-4">
        <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.cb_FinalApproval, new { @checked = "checked" }) No</label> 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FinalApprovalDate, new { @class = "datepicker17", id = "datepicker17"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cb_FinalApproval)
    </div>
</div>
```

I have my checkbox so that by default it is checked. If a user unchecks the box I would like datepicker17 to appear. How can I do this with Jquery?

[image]

I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
<script>
    /* fired when page has loaded - cannot call before page is ready */
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        $("#cb_FinalApproval").click(function () { // Attach to the cb_FinalApproval checkbox                   
            if ($("#cb_FinalApproval").prop("checked") == true) { // we test for the opposite that we desire, as the box will now be checked
                $("#FinalApprovalDate").val("cb_FinalApproval");
                if ($("#cb_FinalApproval").prop("checked") == false) { // we test for the opposite that we desire, as the box will now NOT be checked
                    $("#FinalApprovalDate").val("datepicker17");
                }
            };
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following jQuery (please note this relies on the dom structure in the question, you may want to use a selector that does not rely on the structure instead):

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    // Initially hide datepicker
    $('.datepicker17').show();

    $(".rb").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             $(this).parent().next().hide();
        }
        else {
             $(this).parent().next().show();
        }
    });

})
```

**View**

Note the added `rb` class used for the jQuery selector.

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cb_FinalApproval, "Final Approval Date", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                <div class="col-md-offset-4">
                    <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.cb_FinalApproval, new { @checked = "checked", @class="rb" }) No</label> 
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FinalApprovalDate, new { @class = "datepicker17", id = "datepicker17"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cb_FinalApproval)
                </div>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i84oJB)**

Comment: this works great!! The only issue I have is that when the page is loaded, the checked box should be checked with no datepicker visible, I adjusted your code to $(function () {
                    $('.datepicker17').show();
                    $(".rb").change(function () {
                        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                            $(this).parent().next().hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).parent().next().show();
                        }
                    }); })

Comment: which allows the checkbox to be unchecked and the date field appears and then when it is checked the date field disappears, its just on the page load that I need rid of the date field.

Comment: @Scanner Nice one, did your change get it working as you needed? :)

Comment: I forgot to add in  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){ $(".rb").trigger("change");
                })     at the beginning of the code, but all credit to you for your help, thanks!!

Comment: cheers buddy, thats it functioning as the user wants, a bit back to front but thats what they asked for